# FBSDKShareDialog not showing and returning error 2

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, video, swift3

Hi I've been this week adapting my app to iOs11 and since yesterday to today trying to do repare the share video to facebook button in iOs 11 but without success. I've tried everything, googled, tried everything in stackOverflow but i'm stuck with this. 
The point is everything stopped to work since I changed the way I save my video. I was using ALAsset and changed to PHAsset. 
I don't know if this is the reason but it's imposible to get the facebook prompt to share my video. I've tried every bit of code I seen around here.
My video url is "file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0233.MP4" and except the name of the file, I think everything is okay. My app check if the user is logged and if it has publish permissions to yes. And then it configures the prompt, to display it. But always end up in the error method of the delegate:

```
/**
 Sent to the delegate when the sharer encounters an error.
 - Parameter sharer: The FBSDKSharing that completed.
 - Parameter error: The error.
 */

func sharer(_ sharer: FBSDKSharing!, didFailWithError error: Error!) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

This is the error:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.share error 2.)
```

Here is my code. I don't see what can be happening except that the saved video from phAsset is not compatible with facebook, which I doubt. But maybe somebody here knows more about this than me and can help.

Many thanks in advance!

Here the code I run after the facebook button is pressed:

```
//save video with PHAsset
    self.avHandler.saveWithPHAsset { (void) -> () in

//get url of the video 
                        guard let urlToShare = self.avHandler.self.mergedLocalAssetVideoURL else {
                            return
                        }

                        if FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil
                        {

                            if FBSDKAccessToken.current().hasGranted("publish_actions")
                            {
                                print("permission granted")
                                let video = FBSDKShareVideo(videoURL: urlToShare)
                                let dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
                                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                                    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL.init(string: "fbauth2://")!)
                                    {
                                        dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.native
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogMode.browser
                                    }
                                }


                                let content : FBSDKShareVideoContent = FBSDKShareVideoContent()
    //                                content.contentURL = NSURL.init(string: urlToShare.absoluteString) as! URL
                                let image = UIImage(data: self.recordingInfo.thumbData)
                                let fbimage = FBSDKSharePhoto(image: image, userGenerated: false)
                                content.previewPhoto = fbimage!
                                content.video = video!
                                content.contentURL = urlToShare
                                dialog.delegate = self
                                dialog.shareContent = content
                                dialog.fromViewController = self
    //                            FBSDKShareDialog.show(from: self, with: content, delegate: self)
                                dialog.show()


                            }
                            else
                            {
                                print("don't have permission")

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            "Please login to facebook in the tab menu".displayInfo()
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: Yes, saving the video the old way